# can't use find() in collection instance in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a class:

```
import sys
import os
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

class Collection():
    def __init__(self, db, collection_name):
        self.db = db
        self.collection_name = collection_name

        if not hasattr(self.__class__, 'client'):
            self.__class__.client = MongoClient()

        self.data_base = getattr(self.client, self.db)
        self.collection = getattr(self.data_base, self.collection_name)
```

I created class instances as follows:

```
    def getCollections(self):
        collections_dict = {}
        for i in range(len(self.db_collection_names)):
            collections_dict[self.db_collection_names[i]] = Collection(self.database_name, self.db_collection_names[i])
        return collections_dict
```

`db_collection_names` contains `email_logs`.  I created an `emails` instance as follows:

```
emails = collections_dict['email_logs']
```

`print emails` yields `<collection.Collection instance at 0x105ce6248>`

`print emails.find()` yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 75, in <module>
program.runProgram()
  File "main.py", line 63, in runProgram
print emails.find
AttributeError: Collection instance has no attribute 'find'
```

Why the error?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're bothering to redefine the Pymongo Collection class.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient().my_database  # create an instance of pymongo Database
emails = db.emails  # create an instance of pymongo Collection

emails.find()  # yeilds a pymongo Cursor (containing the query results)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the collection before the `find()` method

```
emails.collection.find()
```